# What is the code for "Numbers, Words and Spaces" in Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match html code in Python, using regular expressions for that. The line I'm working with is "Page 1 of 50" from html.
I googled re documentation and tried the following code :

```
pattern = 'Page [0-9]+ of ([0-9]+)'
#or 
pattern = r'Page [0-9]+ of ([0-9]+)/w'
```

This does not help. How should I do that?

```
@property
def page_count(self):
    content = self.soup.select_one(AllBooksPageLocators.PAGER).string
    pattern = 'Page [0-9]+ of ([0-9]+)'
    matcher = re.search(pattern, content)
    pages = int(matcher.group(1))
    return pages
```

Comment: could you explain what isn't working? The regex, at least, looks fine to me.

Comment: Please provide us with `content`'s content and what is your issue.

Comment: you can replace the spaces with unlimited number of whitespaces to be more general, like: `Page\s*[0-9]+\s*of\s*([0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is [correct](https://regex101.com/r/rHeRPm/1).
The matching group is found at found at

```py
matcher.group(0)
```

But will result in

```py
'Page 1 of 50'
```

You might then look at how to parse your sample of text

Comment: No. OP correctly used `group(1)` because there is `([0-9]+)` with parentheses.

Comment: [Documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). `If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string`. Just confirming what @h4z3 said.